# Need help to figure out the unique computer hardware fingerprint

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I am creating an licencing system for my windows application and for that i need to create an unique computer identity .
for that i am using

**Processor ID** and **Processor Family**

Is this sufficient to create a unique hardware fingerprint or not.

i am little bit confused that **Processor ID**  is unique for all computers or not.

Please provide me an beater idea on that

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101772/win32-processoris-processorid-unique-for-all-computers

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599837/how-to-generate-and-validate-a-software-license-key

Answer (score 2):

The ProcessorID or CPUID are for identifying the model and feature set of the processor (ARM, x86/x64).

The Pentium III supported a Processor Serial Number (PSN). [In addition to only being supported on the Pentium III (and Transmeta's Efficeon and Crusoe processors)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D3%3a_Processor_Serial_Number), [the feature had to be enabled in BIOS and raised privacy concerns.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_III#Controversy_about_privacy_issues)

> So no, ProcessorID is not unique for all of computers. Additionally, it
>   is very likely to not be unique across computers in your company
>   (since many organizations buy multiple computers of the same model).

Answer (score 1):

[This question may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475735/is-wmi-a-good-way-to-making-a-hardware-fingerprint)

I know this answer will be better as comment. But I am new and too low to post comments at the moment :(